# How to find how a container was started: "docker run" or "docker-compose up"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, devops

When accessing a remote machine I'd like to know if a container was started over `docker run` or `docker-compose` or some other means.

Is that even possible?

EDIT: the main reason for this was to find out, where these containers are getting orchestrated, i.e. if the container goes down, will be started again? Where would that configuration be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For investigation purposes I created the most simplest docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  hello:
    image: "hello-world"
```

Then run it with `docker-compose up`

And lastly the normal way: `docker run -it --name cli hello-world`

So I had two stopped containers:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
6a8d53ff45a4        hello-world         "/hello"            9 minutes ago       Exited (0) 9 minutes ago                       cli
d54f7a2ae8b2        hello-world         "/hello"            9 minutes ago       Exited (0) 9 minutes ago                       compose_hello_1
```

Then I compared inspect output of both:

```
diff <(docker inspect cli) <(docker inspect compose_hello_1)
```

I found out that there are labels which compose creates:

```
             "Labels": {}
---
             "Labels": {
                 "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "251ebf43e00417fde81d3c53b9f3d8cd877e1beec00ebbffbc4a06c4db9c7b00",
                 "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                 "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                 "com.docker.compose.project": "compose",
                 "com.docker.compose.service": "hello",
                 "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.1"
             }
```

Also compose uses another network:

```
             "NetworkMode": "default",
---
             "NetworkMode": "compose_default",
```

You should do it on your environment and try to find out differences where you can surely differentiate between both launch ways.

Comment: A good Idea: `docker inspect --format '{{json .Config.Labels}}' ssl_proxy | jq` still it's probably only telling how the container got created, not necessarily how it is managed, but is as close probably as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's impossible. You can only guess it according to some secondary properties doing `docker inspect container-name`.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I've been following the ppid tree also to find more info on how this could have get started, but is not easy... is a pitty this info does not get stored anywhere...